# Why am I getting Object Required error (VBA, Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

Why is the following code wrong?

```
Sub SetFont()
    Dim a1 As Range
    Set a1 = Range("a1")
    SetFontSize (a1)
End Sub

Sub SetFontSize(target As Range)
    target.Font.Size = 11
End Sub
```

I am getting **"Run-time error 424: Object required"** error when calling the `SetFontSize` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not calling a function, you don't need the parentheses when calling `SetFontSize (a1)`.

Just use:

```
SetFontSize a1
```

Comment: You mean parentheses are required only when calling functions?

Comment: You only need parentheses when you are calling a function with parameters, and the function is returning a value to a variable.

Comment: if you want to put parentheses, use `call setfontsize(a1)`, but really, that's complicating things.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about pointing that out, but I agree, it's complicating things.